The $n$-th root in the ring of polynomial over a field containing $\mathbb{C}$
Let $K$ be a field containing the complex number field $\mathbb{C}$, and $f\in K[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$ a polynomial with $n$ variables. Suppose $L$ is an extension
field of $K$ and $f=g^{m}$ for some $m\geq 1$ and $g\in L[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$. Prove there exists $h\in K[X_{1},\dots,X_{n}]$ and $c\in K$ such that $f=c\cdot h^{m}$.

It is always a good idea to provide context when asking for a proof of something. Either tell us where the question came from, why it is important, what your level of Mathematics knowledge is (so people can tailor their answer) or what you have tried so far. Good questions get a lot more answers.

This question is from a competition of Algebra in my university. I tried to use the induction by regarding f as an element in $K(X_{n+1})[X_1,...,X_{n}]$ to solve this problem. But it doesn't work.

Thanks for making the clarification - this ideally should be an edit to the original question, but it really helps a lot.

It suffices to assume the characteristic of $K$ is $0$ (not necessarily an extension of $\mathbb C$). Let $g=a_{I_1}X^{I_1}+a_{I_2}X^{I_2}+\cdots+a_{I_n}X^{I_m}$, where $I_1>I_2>\cdots>I_m$ are $n$-tuples that represent the exponents of $X=(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n)$, and $<$ is a fixed monomial order.
First we show that if $a_{I_1}\in K$, then $a_{I_i}\in K$ for all $1\le i \le m$. Indeed, by induction hypothesis, if $a_{I_1}, \cdots, a_{I_i}$ are all in $K$, then the coefficients of $(m-1)I_1+I_{i+1}$ in $f=g^m$ must be $$ma_{I_1}^{m-1}a_{I_{i+1}}+p(a_{I_2}, a_{I_3}, \cdots, a_{I_i})\in K$$
where $p$ is an integer polynomial. As $m\not=0$ in $K$, $a_{I_{i+1}}\in K$.
Now in general, note that the leading coefficients of $f=g^m$ is $c:=a_{I_1}^m\in K$, therefore $\frac{f}{c} = (\frac{g}{a_{I_1}})^m\in K[X]$, and by the above result, $g/a_{I_1}\in K[X]$.
